# UdpClient - SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm occasionally getting the following exception when I call `udpClient.SendAsync`. It's maybe in 10% of the cases:

> SocketException: An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.

Full code:

```cs
    public static UdpClient Create()
    {
        var client = new UdpClient();
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        // client.EnableBroadcast = true; // adding this does not help either.
        return client;
    }
```

```cs
    using var udpClient = Create();

    _ = await udpClient.SendAsync(datagram, datagram.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 55555))
                               .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I've seen other questions on StackOverflow about the same exception, but that's pretty much all code that creates socket instances, which is not the case here.